# How do I add a window from the resources as a child window?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am creating a windows using win32:

```
HWND mainWnd = CreateWindow(...);
```

Now I can add gui elements as children of mainWnd. However this soon becomes a bit tedious and I want to use the designer built into Visual Studio to help me.
I noticed that under Add Resource there is a Dialog entry. Among the dialogs IDD_FORMVIEW seems the most general so I added one of these. Next I added gui elements to it using the designer.

Now I want to use this as a child of my mainWnd. **How do I do this?**

I found some examples using DialogBox, but I do not want a separate dialog, I want this window as a child of my mainWnd.

Comment: You are heading off in a very wrong direction.  The resource editor is really only suitable to edit dialogs, it is most certainly not a UI designer.  Do take a look at more modern offerings, Winforms and WPF have very effective designers.  Qt does pretty well for C++ code.

Comment: Thanks Hans. The problem is that I have to write unmanaged code (C++). The problem with Qt is that I do not control the message loop since I am developing a plug-in for a 3rd party program.

Comment: @HansPassant: Not quite true. E.g. dialog child windows e.g. for tab controls can be designed this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The designer in Visual Studio is appropriate for creating dialog boxes, not arbitrary windows.

That being said, there are a couple of approaches (in increasing order of difficulty):

1. Make your main window a dialog.  [Petzold's book](http://www.charlespetzold.com/pw5/) has an example of using a dialog as the main window of the program.  (If I recall correctly, it's the calculator example.)
2. Create the dialog and, before you show it, change its style to `WS_CHILD`, change its extended style to `WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT`, and parent it to your main window.  For all the navigation stuff to work, you'll have to add `IsDialogMessage` calls in your message pump.  This is do-able, but it's likely hard to get everything working well.
3. A mixture of 1 and 2 where you create one dialog for your main window, then create a second dialog for the content (with `DS_CONTROL`), and put the second dialog in the first.  I've never tried this approach myself, but it seems like it should work.
4. Write your own code to parse the dialog resource and create the child windows, which is basically re-doing a lot of the work that `CreateDialog` does for you.

Given your desire to use the GUI to design the UI, I suspect only the first solution is simple enough that you would be interested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CreateDialog API to create the window from the resource. If you do not want it to look like a dialog then remove the titlebar style from the resource properties.

Answer (score 0):

To use a dialog created from a dialog resource template you have to specify the DS_CONTROL window style in the template.

Read more about dialog boxes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Dialog resources are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)